# What became of Auguste Liebnitz and family from Hamburg?

Tags: germany, 1930s, hamburg

My great aunt Auguste Liebnitz lived in Hamburg (20.2.1931) at the following address Hamburg 26, Kentzlerweg 13 Ptr.

How could I find out what became of her and her family?

Comment: Hi Allen – welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE! Please take the [tour] to get a quick overview of how the site works. Generally one line questions do not include enough information to provide a good answer. For example, we don't know what you have tried already, so might just tell you things you already know. With questions like this it is important you give the pertinent details, and the sources for your information. For example, where did you find the address? Was your great aunt married, did she have children? etc. You can add details using the [edit] button below your post.

Comment: Do you know how old Auguste was on that date, or what year she was born?  I ask to be sure that our privacy policy in the [help/on-topic] does not apply and to help you work with it if it does. Is the date that you have asked about associated with a particular record that you have located?

Comment: I think the date of birth 1858 is correct as her older brother Johan Heinrich was born in 1856 and their father died in 1861

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too broad to be answered entirely satisfactory here. To determine the whereabouts of a family is the *goal of research* that consists of many steps.

- City directories of Hamburg until 1966 have been digitized by Hamburg university library. You’ll find an [overview at GenWiki](http://wiki-de.genealogy.net/Kategorie:Adressbuch_f%C3%BCr_Hamburg). There is no index, but looking up people should be easy. You’ll find others with this surname (usually the “head of family” or women living alone), their place of living. With a edition available for every year, you can also trace movements within the city or people disappear, indicating e.g. relocations elsewhere or deaths.
- Ancestry.com has civil records for Hamburg (births 1874–1901, marriages 1874–1920, deaths 1874–1950).

  - widow Johanne Catharine Auguste Liebnitz, née Samuel, born 30 November 1858 in Altona, died 11 March 1936
  - marriage with Johann Adam Schenk from Gerlachsheim 24 March 1879
  - marriage with worker Heinrich Richard Liebnitz from Memel, 4 April 1917
  - I could not find any children. You should look for yourself again in the database. The birth records could contain a handwritten link to their marriages and deaths.

Comment: Thanks for the above Info-I dont understand the 1879 marriage to J H Samuel as both her brother and Father were named Johan Heinrich Samuel-she might have had a child called Reinhold who was married to Olga who had three children Annelise born circa 1911,Lottchen  born1914, andReinhold (Jun)born 1918

Comment: @AllenEnLindaSamuel I am sorry, I made a mistake. She married Johann Adam Schenk in 1879.